# Loading ruby config file as per environment

Tags: ruby, thor

I have following Folder structure

```
configs/    
-- dev/    
---- app-config.rb    
-- qa/    
---- app-config.rb    
-- prod/    
---- app-config.rb
```

All app-config.rb will have same structure, but config values will be different

#### app-config.rb

```rb
module App
  module Config
    @@config = {some hash configs}
  end
end
```

Now I am using **Thor** for CLI, so my command will be like 
`thor add CONF`
e.g, `thor add dev` OR `thor add perf`

so depending on CONF param it should read app-config.rb and load @@config, which then I will use in code.

But somehow its not working and I am getting

*uninitialized class variable @@config in App::Config*

Please suggest any design to achieve the same.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the scope of this variables:

http://www.wellho.net/mouth/2609_Scope-of-variables-important-to-Ruby-on-Rails.html

Use $ variable for a global one. As @@ is a Class variable.

You will find this useful:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#creating-rails-environments

Answer (score 0):

```
module App
  module Config
    @@config= {env:"dev"}    
    def self.config
      @@config
    end
  end
end

App::Config.config #=> {:env=>"dev"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're much better off going with a single `app-config.rb` and putting your config variables in a yaml file, just like rails does. Otherwise you have seriously duplicated code.

```
# production.yml
user: mdmoskwa
secret_key: abcd1234
```

Also since you likely want true singleton behavior here, it's best to use the following pattern:

```
# app_config.rb
module Config
  def self.config
    @config ||= YAML.load_file("/path/to/configs/#{Rails.env}.yml")
  end
end

# to use your config variables
user = Config.config["user"]
```